# What does "comparing signs" mean?

Tags: geometry

So read something about using binary space partioning for rendering geometry and i didn't quite get what "you check if it’s on the same side of the camera by comparing signs".

English is not my primary language and if i run the sentence through a translator "signs" will get translatet to "signs" in terms of road sings. If i google "comparing signs" it just gives me explanations to ">", "<", "=" ...

For context:
you can use the cross product of two adjacent sides of a triangle to get the normal of its plane, which can then be used to calculate the coefficients for the standard form of the plane, which will easily determine which side of the plane a triangle is located in (you check if it’s on the same side of the camera by comparing signs) and where to split using linear interpolation.

You compare the sign of the resulting value when putting camera position through the standard form of a plane equation and the same for a vertex of a triangle. If the signs are equal, the vertex is on the same side of the plane as the camera, and is therefore in front of the plane.

Comment: The sign here refers to positive and minus sign. In rendering, what is positive and negative depends on the context; here it probably means whether you’re in front or behind a camera. Signs are sometimes calculated through cross products, and different orientations give a different sign in the cross product